# Set default value for NULL in datatable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

I have the following codes, which I created as extension for datatable in my project. It actually worked. Just wonder if there is any optimization can be made through. Thanks. =)

I understand this question should somehow belong to [CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58024/set-default-value-for-null-in-datatable). Just ask through.

```
<Extension()>
Public Function HasNull(ByVal dataTable As DataTable) As Boolean
    For Each column As DataColumn In dataTable.Columns
        If dataTable.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)().Any(Function(r) r.IsNull(column)) Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function SetDefaultForNull(ByVal dataTable As DataTable) As DataTable
    For Each row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
        For Each col As DataColumn In dataTable.Columns
            Dim value As Object = row(col)
            If IsDBNull(value) Then
                Dim dataType As String = col.DataType.ToString

                Select Case dataType
                    Case "System.DateTime"
                        value = New DateTime
                    Case "System.Decimal", "System.Int16", "System.Int32", "System.Int64"
                        value = 0
                    Case "System.String"
                        value = String.Empty
                    Case "System.Boolean"
                        value = False
                    Case Else
                        value = 0
                End Select
                row(col) = value
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return dataTable
End Function
```

Comment: I would handle the case that the input table is `Nothing`, either throw an `ArgumentNullException` or return `True`/`False`. Also another minor improvement: i would loop the rows instead of the columns. Consider that all columns are non-null except the last. You would loop all rows for all column before you detect a null. If you loop the rows you'd determined that already in the first row(if the last column is null).

Comment: @Tim Schmelter. Thanks for the response. My intention for second function is to set a default value for each cell which is null. So i will anyhow have to loop through each row and column?

Comment: I was primarily referring to the first method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i'll put my comment here, for what it's worth:

According to the first method:
I would handle the case that the input table is `Nothing`, either throw an `ArgumentNullException`  or return `True`/`False`.

Also another minor improvement: i would loop the rows instead of the columns. Consider that all columns are non-null except the last. You would loop all rows for all column before you detect a null. If you loop the rows you'd determined that already in the first row(if the last column is full of nulls).

So something like this:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function HasNull(dataTable As DataTable) As Boolean
    If dataTable Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("dataTable must be initialized", "dataTable")
    End If
    Dim allColumns = dataTable.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn).ToList() ' materialize
    Dim hasNullField As Boolean = dataTable.AsEnumerable().
        Any(Function(row) allColumns.Any(Function(c) row.IsNull(c)))
    Return hasNullField
End Function
```

The second method could use this extension instead to get the default value of all types:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function GetDefaultValue(t As Type) As Object
    If t.IsValueType Then
        Return Activator.CreateInstance(t)
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

The second method itself could then be implemented in this way(make it a `Sub`):

```
<Extension()>
Public Sub SetDefaultForNull(dataTable As DataTable)
    For Each row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
        For Each col As DataColumn In dataTable.Columns
            If row.IsNull(col) Then
                row.SetField(col, col.DataType.GetDefaultValue())
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Tested with this sample data:

```
Dim table As New DataTable
table.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Int32))
table.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
table.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))
table.Rows.Add(1, "test", DateTime.Now)
table.Rows.Add(DBNull.Value, Nothing, Nothing)
table.Rows.Add(Nothing, DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value)
If table.HasNull() Then
    table.SetDefaultForNull()
End If
```

Result:

```
1       test    25.07.2014 15:05:29
0               01.01.0001 00:00:00
0               01.01.0001 00:00:00
```

**Edit**: if you really want to replace `null` strings with empty strings you could add a parameter to `GetDefaultValue`:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function GetDefaultValue(t As Type, replaceNullStringsWithEmpty As Boolean) As Object
    If t.IsValueType Then
        Return Activator.CreateInstance(t)
    ElseIf replaceNullStringsWithEmpty AndAlso t = GetType(String) Then
        Return ""
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

However, i don't like exceptions for a single type, it's also impossible to differentiate between `null` and `""` afterwards. I would do such things as last step where you want to display the strings.

Comment: ,thanks. I made some modification on GetDefaultValue method as I find it wouldn't work for String datatype as it's categorize as none value type. Do you have any better idea?

Comment: @chinz: do you really want to replace `null` strings with empty strings? Why? You won't be able to differentiate between them later. I would replace them at the very last step, when you want to display them somewhere.  Otherwise you still need a `Select Case` to check if it's string.

Comment: i'm not sure if i'm doing it right. I have lots of text box and label controls in my form. I used to check DBNULL with IsDBNull each time i take a value from datatable. somehow,often, I might just left out one or two(when a new column if added into database perhaps?)? So I would just replace all null value with empty string then it will never be forgotten.

Comment: @chinz: you could add a parameter `bool replaceNullWithEmpty` and then check for strings. I've edited my answer to show what i mean.

Comment: It is always better to have an options. =]